# How i can implement date range picker in MUI DataGridPro?

Tags: material-ui, datagrid, daterangepicker, mui-datatable

I want to implement a Date Range picker with DataGrid Pro can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

To implement a date range picker on a cell in the data grid (assuming this is what you are meaning), you would implement the below code:

```
const datePickerColumn: GridColDef[] = [
    {
        field: 'dates',
        headerName: 'Pick Date Range',
        editable: true /* this needs to be set to allow editing */
        type: 'date' /* needs to be set to get the date picker drop down*/
    },
];

<DataGrid
    rows={dateData}
    columns={myDateColumns}
    isCellEditable={(params) => params.row.dates} /* makes the specified column editable */
/>
```

Once implemented, you should now be able to double click on a cell and get a date picker widget.

For more information you can refer to the documentation here: https://mui.com/components/data-grid/editing/

Comment: this will make the specific row editable not the date-range selection implementation on the table.

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean by Date Range picker?

Do you want to have a column containing a date range? If yes, it is better to have two columns. One for start-date the other for end-date

If you want to filter one date column by providing a range, you will have to make a [custom filter operator handling multiple value](https://mui.com/components/data-grid/filtering/#multiple-values-operator)